# How to connect to a local hyper-v virtual machine via SSH?

Tags: linux, windows-8, ssh, terminal, hyper-v

**What I have:**

Windows 8.1 professional edition

**What I want?**

To simulate a circumstance: connect a remote Linux system using SSH.

**What I do:**

Install CentOS 6.4 x64 under the built-in Hyper-v.
It works like a charm.

**What is the question?**

How to connect to this hyper-v CentOS via a terminal by SSH?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest solution is to enable a bridged connection, you can find [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/4fc10e32-fdfd-4e6b-8dac-0a37aedb4ffc/how-to-connect-hyperv-clients-to-the-internet-via-the-hyperv-server?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyp) how to do that. Once you have done this, and started your VM, it will appear on your LAN with an IP just like your host. Then you can ssh into it by means of

```
 ssh me@IP_of_my_VM
```

or whatever you use on Windows, Putty I presume.

Comment: Finally, I open a SSH in CentOS at Hyper-V, figure out its IP and then using putty in windows to connect to this hyper-v instance via this IP,works like a charm.

Comment: Is my case, the IP isn't the same as LAN adapter IP, I have to get into CentOS VM to get IP via command `ip address`

Comment: Also, don't forget to actually install the SSH server `sudo apt install openssh-server`.

Answer (score 14):

#### Step by step instructions for folks who might stumble into this.

**Guest -> Linux on Hyper-V**
**Host -> Your OS (Windows 8/10/11)**

1. Make sure the Guest (Linux) can **access the internet** (using default switch in the hyper-v manager is the easiest).
2. On guest, install **net-tools** and **open ssh server**.
   a. `$ sudo apt-get install net-tools`
   b. `$ sudo apt-get install -y openssh-server`
3. Edit configuration file for openssh after it's installed
   `nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Vi editor is generally available by default. You might need to install nano if you are not comfortable with vi.
4. Find and Uncomment
   `#Password Authentication yes`,
   so it looks like:
   `Password Authentication yes`. **save the file**
5. Reload ssh after these changes
   a. `sudo systemctl disable ssh`
   b. `sudo systemctl enable ssh`
   if above commands are not working, also try these :
   `sudo systemctl stop ssh`
   `sudo systemctl start ssh`
6. **Ensure ssh is running**
   `# systemctl status ssh`
   Now you can peacefully move ahead.
7. On guest, find its IP from the terminal. Use
   a. `ip address` or,
   b. `ip address | grep -i eth0`
   c. Username is your Linux username, and password is your Linux login password.

#### On the Host Machine

7. Use PowerShell to connect directly to the guest, or use programs like Putty. I personally prefer powershell. (Make sure the Hyper V is running)
   E.G: **hostname**: linuxusername, ip: **172.154.123.321** (see No. 7), password (linuxpassword)
   **PowerShell**
   `ssh linuxusername@172.154.123.321`
   Type linuxpassword
   **Putty**:
   same, just input the ip address in the hostname and press enter, type password into the terminal and you should be in there too.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Your answer shows one way how to do it, so I don't understand why it got downvoted. However, please edit your answer and put all code in code boxes (instead of writing it as bold text).

Comment: @Binarus - it leaves out lots of things, such as saving ssh_config after editing it, and it calls the user name the 'hostname'. Likely to confuse a new Linux user.

Comment: May God bless you for this direct answer.

Comment: @Binarus I've added your feedback. I'm sorry the reason I wrote this was to help beginners as the accepted answer is brief and useful only for advanced users.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to chime in because the given answer only covers the use case where you want your VM to also be exposed to the internet, and is also more work than necessary. If you want to get this working on a virtual internal network:

1. Set up the virtual switch as Internal network and apply it to the VM
2. In the Hyper-V manager, under the networking tab, you should see the IPv6 addresses associated with the VM.
3. Adjust the width of the columns if necessary or mouse over to reveal the far right IPv6 address (probably starts with fe80). Connect to this IP address using your software of choice.

In the case of the External network, you should see the IPv4 address it is using on the network tab and should be able to connect to that.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to find the Networking tab. On my version of Hyper-V its hiding at the very bottom of the Hyper-V Manager screen. Not where you expect to find tabs IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Adding to your suggestion, using Powershell to get the IP Address listed in that column made it easier for me: `(Get-Vm -Name NameOfYourVM).NetworkAdapters.IPAddresses`. You may have to run Powershell in Administrator mode if you do not have appropriate policy set.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that I use to SSH into VMs with default switch (dynamic internal IP) with one command:

- Enable static Mac address in the VM: In Hyper-V manager go to VM settings -> Network Adapter -> Advanced Features -> Mac address -> Static.
- In PowerShell add the following to `$profile` file (e.g. open with `notepad $profile`):

```
function GuestVmSsh {
    ssh user@$((arp -a | findstr /i 00-00-00-00-00-00).Split(" ")[2].Trim())
}

Set-Alias guest-vm GuestVmSsh
```

change `user` to your guest system user and `00-00-00-00-00-00` to your static mac address specified in the first step.

- Additionally, to make sure the above script is executed during shell startup, appropriate execution policy should be set. One way is to execute the following as Administrator:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

After that you should be able to SSH into your guest VM by executing `guest-vm` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a universal answer or not, but after failing to see much success using other recommendations, I did the following and it worked:

My guest machine, which is a CentOS 7 box, is using a "default network" switch.

On the guest, I ran the "ifconfig" command to look at the ip for the box:

eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.240.149

I then typed in that IP address to Putty, and lo and behold, it connected.  Magic networking FTW.